# How to make fire disappear after 7 seconds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I need to make fire to be able to disappear after 7 seconds. Is there any way to do that?

I need to know, as after 1 versus 1 game finishes, the fire still stays in that place.

Comment: Do you want to clear all fires at once after 7 seconds or do you want every single fire to last exactly (or at most) 7 seconds?

Comment: all fires at once

Answer (score 1):

if you have a Command Block set to clear the positions of each fire block.

```
setblock X Y Z air
```

or if the arena is flat you can use the Fill command that would be easier.

```
fill X1 Y1 Z1 X2 Y1 Z2 air
```

If you need more information I'd be happy to help.